# print either int or double with selfmade print method in java

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I have a programm that creates 2D arrays of ints and double (some are int, some are double). I wrote a method to print those arrays as a map to the console. But instead of having two methods for int and double each, i wondered if its possible to accept both int and double as a parameter.

This is my print function:

```
private void printMap(int map[][]){
    for (int i=0; i<map.length;i++){
        for (int j=0; j<map[i].length;j++){
            if(map[i][j]<1000)System.out.print(" ");
            if(map[i][j]<100)System.out.print(" ");
            if(map[i][j]<10)System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(imap[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }   
}
```

Right now i have 2 times the same except for the params, like:

```
    private void print_intMap(int map[][]){..}
    private void print_doubleMap(double map[][]){..}
```

and I want it to be like

```
    private void printMap(/*either int or double*/){..}
```

Any ideas?
thx in advance

Comment: Assuming you want to stick with primitives I don't think you can avoid this.

Comment: You'll not inbuild java classes have versions for individual pritive types. For example Arrays.binarySearch has a char[], int[] double[] etc varietys

Comment: What do you want to happen a double has more than one decimal place .e.g. "    0.0    1.123 "

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) type as your array type. It is extended by both [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html). This type can be created from either `double` or `int` primitive types via [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) which will do this conversion for you automatically.

```
Number doubleNumber = 1.0;
Number intNumber = 1;
```

Then your code would look like:

```
private void printMap(Number map[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            if(map[i][j].intValue() < 1000) System.out.print(" ");
            if(map[i][j].intValue() < 100) System.out.print(" ");
            if(map[i][j].intValue() < 10) System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(imap[i][j].intValue() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }   
}
```

Comment: BTW `int` and `double` are not `Number` You can't autobox an `int[]` to a `Number[]`

Comment: yes, this is true.  i updated my answer to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best option here would be to use polymorphism.  Essentially, you create two methods with the same name.  The only difference will be the parameters- one will take an int, and the other will take a double. For example

```
private void printMap(int map[][])
private void printMap(double map[][])
```

This would allow you to call printMap with your array without needing a check on the type.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called "Method Overloading": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading
Here is a great example fiting with what you want to do! :

```
public class MainClass {
  // method printArray to print Integer array
  public static void printArray(Integer[] inputArray) {
    // display array elements
    for (Integer element : inputArray)
      System.out.printf("%s ", element);
    System.out.println();
  }
  // method printArray to print Double array
  public static void printArray(Double[] inputArray) {
    // display array elements
    for (Double element : inputArray)
      System.out.printf("%s ", element);
    System.out.println();
  }

  // method printArray to print Character array
  public static void printArray(Character[] inputArray) {
    // display array elements
    for (Character element : inputArray)
      System.out.printf("%s ", element);

    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // create arrays of Integer, Double and Character
    Integer[] integerArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    Double[] doubleArray = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7 };
    Character[] characterArray = { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' };

    System.out.println("Array integerArray contains:");
    printArray(integerArray); // pass an Integer array
    System.out.println("\nArray doubleArray contains:");
    printArray(doubleArray); // pass a Double array
    System.out.println("\nArray characterArray contains:");
    printArray(characterArray); // pass a Character array
  }
}
```

Taken from this website: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0100__Class-Definition/Usingoverloadedmethodstoprintarrayofdifferenttypes.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. A few things you *can* do are:

- Method overloading. You can make methods with the same name, as long as they have different parameters. E.g.:

  ```
  private void printMap(int map[][]) {...}
  private void printMap(double map[][]) {...}
  ```

  You can then call `printMap` with either and `int[][]` or a `double[][]` as the argument, and it will execute the corresponding method.
- Make it accept a [`Number[][]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html):

  ```
  private void printMap(Number map[][]) {...}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the method taking as parameter the double and make a cast when calling the method with an 'int'

```
printMap((double)map[][])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest converting the int variable into double variable, and then use it in your class (i believe it is the simplest solution):

```
int x=7;
double y=(double)x;  
print_doubleMap(y);
//or  
print_doubleMap((double)x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection but it is ugly

```
public static void print(int[][] ints) {
    printMatrix(ints);
}

public static void print(double[][]] doubles) {
    printMatrix(doubles);
}

public static void printMatrix(Object o) {
    int len1 = Array.getLength(o);
    for(int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
         Object o2 = Array.get(o, i);
         int len2 = Array.getLength(o2);
         for(int j = 0; j < len2; j++) 
             System.out.printf("%4s ", Array.get(o2, j);
         System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is any cleaner than just copying a method.

```
public static void print(int[][] ints) {
    for(int[] is : ints) {
        for(int i : is)
            System.out.printf("%4d ", i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```